# How to do mobile app + REST API authentiction without third party authentication providers?

Tags: node.js, authentication, mobile, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am writing a REST API (Node.js) that will be consumed by a mobile app (React Native). The app will require a user to sign in with credentials which should be used to authenticate against the API. I also need the app to remember that the user is logged in so that they are not forced to re login each time that the app is opened.

What is the best practice when it comes to doing this authentication without using a third party Authentication/Authorization provider such as Auth0, Okta, etc?

I suspect that I need to use some sort of an OAuth2/OpenID Connect implementation with JWT's and using the implicit grant flow with PKCE. Problem is that from what I understand, it would require me to either roll out my own OAuth server or to pay for a third party one (ie one of the above).

Is there any accepted and secure way that I can do this with my own API issuing the JWT tokens? How do I add PKCE to that and how do I handle refresh tokens with the mobile app? How do popular mobile apps do this?

Any help or pointing to relevant tutorials would be highly appreciated. Anything I could find is either promotional material from the third party providers above or stuff that really doesn't seem to be all the secure.

Comment: https://blog.usejournal.com/persisting-user-authentication-in-a-react-native-app-778e028ac816 check this link out maybe it can help you out

Comment: Thanks @MaartendeWolf! This blog post though seems to deal more on how to store the token in AsyncStorage with React Native. This is a part of what I am looking for, but more so, what I need is the mechanism to actually authenticate on the backend. For example, do I just generate a token (JWT) and send to the mobile app? How do I handle refresh tokens to make sure that the user is not kicked out of their sessions but also that the token is not long-lived?